# Como posso fazer um conjunto de códigos PHP serem colocados para funcionar dentro de uma modal apenas ao chamá-la?

Tags: php, javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Eu estou desenvolvendo minha primeira página de pagamento para o meu e-commerce (sou um programador iniciante).
Dentro desta página uma das formas de pagamento está dentro de uma modal feita em **bootstrap**.
O conteúdo desta modal são códigos em **PHP** que fazem o pagamento ser realizado.
O que ocorre é que, independentemente de abrir a modal ou não, o código PHP é chamado e colocado em ação. Quero que esse código seja posto em prática **apenas ao abrir a modal**.
Alguém pode me dar o direcionamento de como fazer isso?

Vou inserir uma imagem do código mostrando o início da modal só para ajudar no entendimento de como está o código PHP dentro dela.
[Código PHP na modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waANY.png)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Se o seu arquivo for .php  com ou sem modal, a função PHP vai retornar um arquivo HTML.

Já quem faz a função de abri a modal é JavaScript.

Em resumo crie o arquivo completo .php e ele vai gerar seu HTML dinâmico.

Agora se você quer que a cada vez que abri o modal a pagina mude (dinâmica) de valor, ai é um processo com javascript via JSON + php, seria essa a alternativa.
Pesquise no google sobre dois assuntos:

==>> HTML Form JSON PHP

==>> Ajax Php

Tanto é possível enviar como receber dados via Json, mas ai é preciso um estudo aprofundado sobre o assunto.

Fazer o que você deseja é algo complexo de explicar, ou a sua pergunta não está bem formulada. Por favor não insira imagem, ao invés disso insira o código dentro da sua pergunta, isso facilita o entendimento e testes.